# How to set BlackBerry 9900 Simulator's NFC Options?

Tags: blackberry, nfc, blackberry-simulator

I am developing a nfc project and i need to test it on blackberry simulator. I worked for set simulator NFC options like in this page(http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/34443/Test_an_NFC_app_1627607_11.jsp). But i couldnt run it, i always get "Couldnt connect to NFC device.Check that the components are started properly and that the URL is correct."

here is the screen shots step by step;

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]